# Issue with JSON & PHP. Trying to display tweets: code knows amount of tweets but shows as 'null'

Tags: json, twitter

I'm using **[tweets_json.php](https://gist.github.com/planetoftheweb/5914179)** (with *tmhOAuth.php*).
I filled the keys from the Twitter API and uploaded cacert.pem

I wrote the following code

```
<?php

$_tweet = array();

$_i = 0;
$_mycurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($_mycurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt ($_mycurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$_url = "http://www.joycot.com/test/plugins/tweet/tweets_json.php?screen_name=USERNAME"; 
curl_setopt ($_mycurl, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
$_web_response =  curl_exec($_mycurl); 


$_array = json_decode($_web_response, true);
if ($_web_response) {
  foreach($_array as $_value) {
    $_tweet[$_i] = $_value->text;
    $_i++;
  }
}

$_data['tweets'] = $_tweet;

echo json_encode($_data);

?>
```

It is showing the correct amount of tweets but I can't find the way to display the JSON data.

{"tweets":[*null,null,null*...]}

What am I doing wrong? I started to learn about json just few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it almost right. You only have to replace the line:

```
$_array = json_decode($_web_response, true);
```

by:

```
$_array = json_decode($_web_response);
```

because if the 2nd argument is true, the result will be given with a different type of array: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php